# Can I put different note lengths on guitar pro (in one bar )

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to put different note lengths in one bar above or below each other but when I change a note in guitar pro then other notes change too, so I have to use ties for other notes and that's very nerve-racking 
Do you know any way to solve this problem ? 
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: For starters, your bars don't add up to the time signature.

Comment: @user45266 Don't blame OP for not fillilng measure correctly if they struggle to set proper note lengths.

Answer (score 3):

[You should look into using multiple voices](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000143365-GP7-5-Access-the-Multivoice-feature-in-Guitar-Pro-7-5) (find a similar article for your GP version) - but make sure it's still playable. If it isn't playable, you should look into using multiple instruments.

To summarise the article, here's a screenshot showing what I mean (complete with some handy freehand circles). My screenshot is of Guitar Pro 7 so the icons might be in a different place in your version's UI, but they should look the same (or similar enough):

[image: Multiple voices in Guitar Pro 7]

- To switch between voices, you click on one of the numbers circled in red. You can have up to four different voices.
- To view all four voices at the same time, so all of the notes are a solid black and not greyed out like in my screenshot, toggle the button circled in yellow. I personally like to only work on one voice at a time when writing music so tend to leave it toggled off, but if I want to see how readable my music is as a whole (ie the bar lines don't cross, it doesn't look too cramped, etc) then I'll toggle this.