# Transcribing a PDF to Guitar Pro

Tags: notation, sheet-music, engraving, guitar-pro

I am very new to Guitar Pro and music theory/notation in general. I have a pdf with some music that I want to input into Guitar Pro, but it seems like the time signature doesn't match with the notes in bars. Is the file wrong or am I not understanding something?

I attached the first line of what I have.
[image: Four measures in 6/8 time in standard notation and guitar tab]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I put different note lengths on guitar pro (in one bar )](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/can-i-put-different-note-lengths-on-guitar-pro-in-one-bar)

Comment: @Aaron I see that the bars are split between two voices but I can't figure out how exactly

Comment: The proposed duplicate addresses how to do the Guitar Pro entry. See [Too many notes in this measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/53041/too-many-notes-in-this-measure) for an explanation of the seeming mismatch between notation and time signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The reason the notes and time signature seem not to match up is that there are two separate "voices" happening simultaneously. This idea is discussed in [Too many notes in this measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/53041/too-many-notes-in-this-measure) and linked Q&A.
2. To identify the two voices, just know that the dotted quarter notes are one voice, and the eighth rests/notes are the other.
3. GuitarPro allows for multiple voices (up to four) using the **Edit -> Voices** menu. [Can I put different note lengths on guitar pro (in one bar)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/can-i-put-different-note-lengths-on-guitar-pro-in-one-bar) discusses this and includes a link to the GuitarPro help center.